# combining data frames using a range for columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 data frames. one consists of data like:
[image: df 1]

The other kind of looks like this:
[image: df 2]

I want to combine them to add tag from the second to the first using the ranges so it would look like this.
[image: result]

Basically I need to map the column tag to the first dataframe using the person, experiment and the value ranges. So far I have no idea how to achieve this. Is this even possible?

Comment: you already have the data, post it as a code so anyone trying to find you the answer don't have to manually create the dataframe.  Review the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think the penultimate row of the second data frame is not followed the rule in the range of the first data frame.